# Got message notification messaging application cChatify Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, push-notification, notifications

I want to send to browser push notification or something similar on receiving a new message. Also, I would like to send notifications to phones on receiving messages in my app. Something like "you received a new message" notification for the user when he got a message.  where to start I have never done something like this I don't know what to Google :D.

I read One signaill documentation, but it seems that it is not for me(notifications are for everyone on a system, not just for the user who received the message) . my app is laravel backend and JS on frontend.